# Elementor: Element Floated to Right of Inner Content Affects Content Links - How to Fix?

Tags: z-index, elementor, floating

Using Elementor Pro: I have a floating element (global) that is an image with a link to a quote page. Visibly everything is okay. The problem is when scrolling, the floating element code covers the inner content, making the inner content links inaccessible. I have changed the Z index on the inner content to be higher than the floating quote element but now as you scroll down the page, the floating quote element link is 'hidden' by the higher Z index of the inner content. Is there a way for me to reduce the dimension of the code 'box' for the floating element so that it doesn't impact the inner content or some other way to have links work properly at all times when scrolling?

Answer (score 0):

After trying different scenarios and options available, I was able to change the size of the element by using inline(auto) for the image size. This reduced the 'coverage' area of the element. However, the absolute positioning was more of an issue than I thought it would be (across various desktop screen sizes - mobile/tablet have alternate setup, so only desktop was affected). I made a decision to remove the floating element and add an item in the sticky nav, so access to the request for quote is still continually visible in the nav.